# Java streams and lazy collections

Tags: java, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I have a method which returns a `Collection` of objects by performing some costly operation (e.g. using a database for resolving objects by ther ID).

Let's use this method as an example:

```java
public static Collection<Integer> getInts()
{
    return IntStream.range(1, 100)
            .peek((value) -> System.out.printf("getInts(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Then I have another method which checks if an object which matches a predicate exists in that collection:

```java
public static boolean primeExists()
{
    return getInts().stream()
        .peek((value) -> System.out.printf("primeExists(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
        .anyMatch(Main::isPrime); // checks if there is a prime number
}
```

By running this code, I have noticed that the `peek` in `getInts()` method prints 10 times, one for each number, even though the `primeExists()` actually needs only the first two elements.

Here is a full code example:

```java
public class Main
{
    private static boolean isPrime(int n)
    {
        if (n < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
        {
            if (n % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static Collection<Integer> getInts()
    {
        return IntStream.range(1, 10)
                .peek((value) -> System.out.printf("getInts(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static boolean primeExists()
    {
        return getInts().stream()
                        .peek((value) -> System.out.printf("primeExists(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
                        .anyMatch(Main::isPrime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        primeExists();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
getInts(): iterating over [1]
getInts(): iterating over [2]
getInts(): iterating over [3]
getInts(): iterating over [4]
getInts(): iterating over [5]
getInts(): iterating over [6]
getInts(): iterating over [7]
getInts(): iterating over [8]
getInts(): iterating over [9]
primeExists(): iterating over [1]
primeExists(): iterating over [2]
```

How can I change this code to get this output instead:

```
getInts(): iterating over [1]
getInts(): iterating over [2]
primeExists(): iterating over [1]
primeExists(): iterating over [2]
```

Is it possible to get this behaviour without changing the `getInts()` method to return an intermediate `Stream`?

I think that the ideal solution is to return a lazy collection from `getInts()` (e.g. a collection whose elements are created only when they are actually iterated). Is there a way to create such collections in Java?

Comment: "a collection whose elements are created only when they are actually iterated" That's a `Stream`. How about returning a `IntStream` from `getInts`?

Comment: `getInts()` should return a `Stream`, not a collection, or you need to take the effort to write a custom `Collection` implementation to lazily populate itself, which will not be easy to do.

Comment: `getInts` collects the stream. Collecting a stream is a terminal operation and usually consumes the full stream. I am not aware of "lazy collections", you'd use a stream for that use case. Plus, you must change the `getInts()` method if its return value should be built lazily

Comment: Lazy collection: `class LazyInts extends AbstractCollection<Integer> { @Override public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
  return IntStream.range(1, 100) .peek(value -> System.out.printf("getInts(): iterating over [%d]\n", value)) .boxed().iterator(); }
  @Override public int size() { return 99; }
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**.

Okay, I have answered the question. But let's provide a whole bunch of context:

> I think that the ideal solution is to return a lazy collection from getInts() (e.g. a collection whose elements are created only when they are actually iterated). Is there a way to create such collections in Java?

You're confused about terminology. Often in officially defined systems (and a programming language is certainly far more specifically defined than your usual human-to-human conversations), terminology gains a far more specific, far more detailedly defined meaning.

In your head, 'collection' could be lazy, why not, right? Collection is a word, in a dictionary, nothing in the dictionary dictates it MUST be eager.

But in java, *`j.u.Collection` **IMPLIES** eager*. Asking for a lazy collection, 'collection' there referring to the english word, that makes sense. asking for 'a lazy Collection', with collection referring specifically to `java.util.Collection`, **makes no sense**. It's like asking for: "A circle but with a corner". It's an oxymoron. Given that you're in java land, using the word 'collection' and intending for that to be taken as the dictionary word and not `j.u.Collection` is a mistake: Words serve to communicate ideas, if the words don't do the job right, you've chosen bad words. It is, naturally, virtually impossible to attempt to disambiguate 'collection - in the sense of english dictionary' and 'collection - in the sense of j.u.Collection', so find another word to convey that notion.

So, what is java's official term for 'a lazy collection-as-in-dictionary'? **It is `Stream`**.

Said differently, you have a method whose return type is "EagerCollection" (Except in java we just call that Collection), and are asking: Is there any way to make that non-eager? Well, no. The spec is literally telling you it has to be eager.

Thinking about the API of a hypothetical 'lazy collection', and going by the API of `j.u.Collection` for inspiration, it just wouldn't make sense. Lots of API needs to either:

- Be removed entirely for not making sense / having nasty side-effects we would never want to expose.
- Document that it 'consumes' the collection, with no way to return, and/or have ridiculous side-effects such as taking an hour and allocating 2 GB worth of RAM.
- Just isn't a thing you generally would be interested in.
- Needs to throw something.
- Needs to return magic values that have weird meanings, such as `size()` being specced to return -1 for infinite collections and -2 for 'I have no idea, I might even be infinite'.
- Handcuffs the notion into eliminating the ability of such a concept to apply to use cases even though they feel right (such as adding the handcuff that lazy collections are nevertheless **required** to accurately report size() in a quick and non-destructive manner, which means you can't make a lazy collection to represent data being piped in across the network).

This is *why* `Stream` exists: Different API was required. This is *why* `java.util.Collection` (and particularly, `java.util.List`) inherently means 'eager'. Even though a few things (really, just `iterator()`, almost every other method is non-sensical or not implementable in a fast and non-destructive manner) could also apply to 'lazy collections'.

As a trivial example, `.get(1000)` often involves either destruction (I could give you the 1000th element, but in doing so, elements 0-999 are consumed and can never be returned again, so if you call `.get(500)` afterwards, an exception will have to occur), or caching (I will allocate some memory and pull 1000 elements, caching 0-999, so that `.get(500)` later does actually work, though it grabs from cache).

Instead in streams, you'd write `.skip(1000).findFirst()` which is about as simple and which is far more accurate in what it *actually does* - whereas with `.get(1000)` I have no idea if that is going to create a cache or crash or how the heck is that going to work, I'd have to read the docs, with `.skip(1000).findFirst()` it's obvious from just that little bit of text: That will destroy elements 0-999 (pull them from the source and discard them, I can never return to these).

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `Stream` instead of `Collection`. As while generating the collection it will read all values from the stream. So `pick` gets called 10 times.

Updated program.

```
public class Main {

    public static boolean isPrime(Integer n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 2; (i * i) <= n; i++) {
            if ((n % i) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static Stream<Integer> getInts() {
        return IntStream.range(1, 10).peek((value) -> System.out.printf("getInts(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
                .boxed();
    }

    public static boolean primeExists() {
        return getInts().peek((value) -> System.out.printf("primeExists(): iterating over [%d]\n", value))
                .anyMatch(Main::isPrime);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        primeExists();
    }

}
```

The output:

```
getInts(): iterating over [1]
primeExists(): iterating over [1]
getInts(): iterating over [2]
primeExists(): iterating over [2]
```

As it will fetch one element and process it so it will print `getInts()` and `primeExists()` for each element.

Comment: The question asks: "Is Y possibly __without__ doing X" and you answer with: "Here is X".  This is not what OP is interested in. (Y = be lazy, X = changing the return type to `Stream`).